# Python - how to optimize iterator in file parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, generator

I get files that have NTFS audit permissions and I'm using Python to parse them. The raw CSV files list the path and then which groups have which access, such as this type of pattern:

```
E:\DIR A, CREATOR OWNER FullControl
E:\DIR A, Sales FullControl
E:\DIR A, HR Full Control
E:\DIR A\SUBDIR, Sales FullControl
E:\DIR A\SUBDIR, HR FullControl
```

My code parses the file to output this:

```
File Access for: E:\DIR A
CREATOR OWNER,FullControl
Sales,FullControl
HR,FullControl

File Access For: E:\DIR A\SUBDIR
Sales,FullControl
HR,FullControl
```

I'm new to generators but I'd like to use them to optimize my code. Nothing I've tried seems to work, so here is the original code (I know it's ugly). It works but it's very slow. The only way I can do this is by parsing out the paths first, put them in a list, make a set so that they're unique, then iterate over that list and match them with the path in the second list, and list all of the items it finds. Like I said, it's ugly but works.

```
import os, codecs, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') // to prevent cp-932 errors on screen

file = "aud.csv"
outfile = "access-2.csv"


filelist = []
accesslist = []
with codecs.open(file,"r",'utf-8-sig') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        newline = line.split(',')
        folder = newline[0].replace("\"","")
        user = newline[1].replace("\"","")
        filelist.append(folder)
        accesslist.append(folder+","+user)

newfl = sorted(set(filelist))

def makeFile():
 print "Starting, please wait"
 for i in range(1,len(newfl)):
  searchItem = str(newfl[i])
  with codecs.open(outfile,"a",'utf-8-sig') as output:
    outtext = ("\r\nFile access for: "+ searchItem + "\r\n")
    output.write(outtext)
    for item in accesslist:
        searchBreak = item.split(",")
        searchTarg = searchBreak[0]
        if searchItem == searchTarg:
            searchBreaknew = searchBreak[1].replace("FSA-INC01S\\","")
            searchBreaknew = str(searchBreaknew)
            # print(searchBreaknew)
            searchBreaknew = searchBreaknew.replace(" ",",")
            searchBreaknew = searchBreaknew.replace("CREATOR,OWNER","CREATOR OWNER")
            output.write(searchBreaknew)
```

How should I optimize this?

EDIT:

Here is an edited version. It works MUCH faster, though I'm sure it can still be fixed:

```
import os, codecs, sys, csv
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

file = "aud.csv"
outfile = "access-3.csv"


filelist = []
accesslist = []
with codecs.open(file,"r",'utf-8-sig') as csvinfile:
    auditfile = csv.reader(csvinfile, delimiter=",")
    for line in auditfile:
        folder = line[0]
        user = line[1].replace("FSA-INC01S\\","")
        filelist.append(folder)
        accesslist.append(folder+","+user)

newfl = sorted(set(filelist))

def makeFile():
 print "Starting, please wait"
 for i in xrange(1,len(newfl)):
  searchItem = str(newfl[i])
  outtext = ("\r\nFile access for: "+ searchItem + "\r\n")
  accessUserlist = ""
  for item in accesslist:
        searchBreak = item.split(",")
        if searchItem == searchBreak[0]:
            searchBreaknew = str(searchBreak[1]).replace(" ",",")
            searchBreaknew = searchBreaknew.replace("R,O","R O")
            accessUserlist += searchBreaknew+"\r\n"
  with codecs.open(outfile,"a",'utf-8-sig') as output:
    output.write(outtext)
    output.write(accessUserlist)
```

Comment: Switch to use `csv` module will narrow down reading the file to two lines of code.

Comment: I'm looking at the guide here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. Does this mean it will automatically parse out the data? In other words, the csv module sees each line as data so I don't have to remove the quotation marks, for example?

Comment: I took your advice; I did that and I also pushed all of the writes to the end so I'm not constantly writing one static line and then loop for the other lines. It's running faster but I'd like to learn how to use generators on the loops if that's practical.

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm misguided from your used `.csv` file extension.
Your given expected output isn't compatible with **csv**, as inside a record no `\n` possible.
Proposal using a generator returning record by record:

```
class Audit(object):
    def __init__(self, fieldnames):
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames
        self.__access = {}

    def append(self, row):
        folder = row[self.fieldnames[0]]
        access = row[self.fieldnames[1]].strip(' ')
        access = access.replace("FSA-INC01S\\", "")
        access = access.split(' ')
        if len(access) == 3:
            if access[0] == 'CREATOR':
                access[0] += ' ' + access[1]
                del access[1];
            elif access[1] == 'Full':
                access[1] += ' ' + access[2]
                del access[2];

        if folder not in self.__access:
            self.__access[folder] = []

        self.__access[folder].append(access)

    # Generator for class Audit
    def __iter__(self):
        record = ''
        for folder in sorted(self.__access):
            record = folder + '\n'
            for access in self.__access[folder]:
                record += '%s\n' % (','.join(access) )

            yield record + '\n'
```

How to use it:

```
def main():
    import io, csv
    audit = Audit(['Folder', 'Accesslist'])

    with io.open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as csc_in:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csc_in, delimiter=","):
            audit.append(row)

    with io.open(outfile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as txt_out:
        for record in audit:
            txt_out.write(record)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - csv:1.0***

Comment: That works pretty well, but I need to parse the results differently. Let me tweak it a bit and then I'll mark it as an answer. Your version took like 30 seconds.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it does answer the question of how to optimize it. For some reason, it seems to output numbers while it runs and  I still want to format the output differently, but this certainly does what I asked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, I'll add that. I did add an example of the expected output in the original post. The original post said the original code worked, it was just slow.

Comment: @Tensigh: Updated Answer writing `txt Record` using `generator`